# Why printf doesnt work when *(int *)(0) = 0; exists

Tags: c

I have following code:

```
main ()
{
    printf("Hello world !");
    *(int *)(0) = 0;
}
```

When I compiled this code and ran, it didn't print the string to console.
After that, I modified a little:

```
main ()
{
    printf("Hello world !\n");
    *(int *)(0) = 0;
}
```

And, it worked !

I think the mystery behind is `*(int *)(0) = 0;` but don't know why !

Ps. I'm using gcc 4.8.2 to compile.

Comment: Console output is buffered, if you crash before the buffer is printed then you lose its contents.

Comment: Considering that what you changed is the string being printed, not the `*(int*)(0)=0`, why do you think that line explains the change in `printf()`'s behavior?

Answer (score 6):

The immediate reason is that `FILE *` operations are buffered, and `stdout` in particular is usually line-buffered (when it's interactive, at least). If no `\n` is seen and `fflush` is not called explicitly before the crash, nothing will actually be written to the underlying file descriptor.

The greater problem is that dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR**. There are absolutely no constraints on what might happen. If the compiler can prove that `printf` will always return, then the UB is allowed to propagate to before the call, making the entirety of `main` UB. That said, it is quite difficult for the compiler to prove this, and in particular since `FILE` usually involves a vtable it's not actually true. But the point is that you can't even trust UB to wait until a particular time.

Answer (score 0):

fflush(stdout) right after your printf and you will see the string before the crash.